# Postman is using which validator for json schema

Tags: postman, jsonschema, ajv

I am trying to understand the postman environment that is used for json schema validation. If I write the tests as shown below. the first test I am using the AJV validator.

And on second test, i dont know what is the validator being used. Can please some explain how the second test works specifically what validator is being used in this case?

Thanks.

I am using Postman v6.7.4.

[image: Schema test in postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using Ajv in both cases here. The Postman helper is using that module internally to validate.

You could also place those or any other options as a second argument in the jsonschema helper function.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/#validating-response-structure

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for your reply. But what you mean by this line : "You could also place those or any other options as a second argument in the jsonschema helper function."  What do you mean by "those" , "any other options" and "jsonschema helper function" ?

Comment: In your first script you have an object of options, logger in your example, that one and the ones available in the Ajv module can be added to the built-in Postman helper. For example: `jsonSchema(schema, {option})`